# Deserialize Nested JSON with C# Without Class Declaration

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to `deserialize` an object dynamically but unsure what the syntax is:

The `JSON` looks like this:

```
  "Id": 2750,
      "Rev": 1,
      "Fields": {
        "System.AreaPath": "test",
        "System.TeamProject": "proj",
        "System.IterationPath": "Ipath",
        "System.WorkItemType": "type"
}
```

I know they can be accessed like this:

```
var resultString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(resultString);
string ID= jsonObject["id"].ToString();
```

But I am not sure how to get to the values nested in Fields directly.
I know I can iterate through `jsonObject["Fields"]` but I want to access them via something like `jsonObject["Fields\\System.AreaPath"].ToString()`; or whichever is the correct syntax, if it exists that is.

Comment: `jsonObject["Fields"]["System.AreaPath"].ToString()`?

Comment: That's it thank you.

Comment: Why not de-serialize in a standard object and work with it